# Sed with inner command and with regex group reference

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I've been struggling with the following problem:

I have a file with the following content

```
1521471079313,219,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,177,0,35
1521471080337,263,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,169,0,0
1521471081404,245,HTTP Request 12,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,5134,201,1,1,210,0,37
1521471082453,125,HTTP Request 13,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,8910,201,1,1,106,0,0
1521471083381,217,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,188,0,0
1521471084402,303,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,226,0,41
```

the first item in the list is an epoc timestamp and I want to convert it to a human readable one.

I tried the following command

```
cat file.csv|sed -E  "s/^([0-9]*)(,.*)/$(date -r \1 '+%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S')\2/p"
```

And it seemed to work but then I saw that it would convert it to:

```
01-01-1970:01:00:01,245,HTTP Request 13,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,8910,201,1,1,219,0,43
01-01-1970:01:00:01,276,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,217,0,0
01-01-1970:01:00:01,276,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,217,0,0
01-01-1970:01:00:01,242,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,216,0,34
01-01-1970:01:00:01,242,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,216,0,34
01-01-1970:01:00:01,147,HTTP Request 12,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,5134,201,1,1,119,0,0
01-01-1970:01:00:01,147,HTTP Request 12,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,5134,201,1,1,119,0,0
```

all timestamps look like "the beginning of time :-)" and not what I wanted.

I know that I have a command substitution in the sed and also two group references based on the former regex in the sed command but why it does not work stumps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sed -r "s/^([0-9]+)(,.*)/echo \$(date -d @\1)\2/" sampl3.log > log.sh && bash log.sh
```

But you have to be secure, that no evil commands are contained in the log, and adapt your date format.

```
Mi 2. Jul 01:21:53 CEST 50183,219,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,177,0,35
Mi 2. Jul 01:38:57 CEST 50183,263,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,169,0,0
Mi 2. Jul 01:56:44 CEST 50183,245,HTTP Request 12,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,5134,201,1,1,210,0,37
Mi 2. Jul 02:14:13 CEST 50183,125,HTTP Request 13,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,8910,201,1,1,106,0,0
Mi 2. Jul 02:29:41 CEST 50183,217,HTTP Request 14,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,17665,204,1,1,188,0,0
Mi 2. Jul 02:46:42 CEST 50183,303,HTTP Request 11,200,OK,PROD 50 rpm 1-10,text,true,,30268,202,1,1,226,0,41
```

Comment: This is the one that actually worked for me after killing the last tree digits of the timestamp: `sed -E "s/^([0-9]{10})[0-9]{3}(,.*)/echo \$(date -r \1 '+%m-%d-%Y:%H:%M:%S')\2/" rpm_50_prod_res.csv > log.sh && bash log.sh` This because some of the params you gave do not work on a Mac... Forgot to tell that

Comment: Well, my impression was, that neither the concrete day format, nor the sed syntax was the problem, but evaluation time of the \1 in the sed function, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You can parse a csv file easily with GNU `awk`. Your `$1` value is an EPOCH value in milli-seconds. You can use `strftime()` call to print the human readable format, after dividing the value by 1000 (i.e. to convert to seconds)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=strftime("%c",($1/1000))}1' file
```

and for in-place edit, use `gawk` or move the output to a temporary file and revert it back to the original

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/abc.XXXXXX)
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=strftime("%c",($1/1000))}1' file > "$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" file
```

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: Probably correct but the question was really for sed because I was also interested in how to get the group reference to work in an inner command on sed. And strftime does not seem to work on macos `awk: calling undefined function strftime`

Comment: Thanks though! after installing gawk on my mac it worked fine! I'll have to give credit to the @user-unknown as his answer came closer to my question and that answer also worked fine even though it is way 'dirty-er'

Comment: @Ivonet : Cheers! No problem